# Dart method types doing odd things

Tags: dart, generics

I have the following Dart code:

```dart
void main() {
  provide(1, 'A');
}

void provide<A>(A one, A two) {
  print('one $one two $two');
}
```

In java the call to provide will give a compile time error  as the two parameters should be both of type A. With java as soon as you pass an argument to a typed parameter that defines the type.

My understanding is that with Dart if I don't follow 'provide' with a type then the type is dynamic.

To get the above code to work correctly in dart I have to write:

```dart
void main() {
  provide<int>(1, 'A');
}

void provide<A>(A one, A two) {
  print('one $one two $two');
}
```

This will now give a compile type error as 'A' is not an int.

This however is error prone as the user is likely to forget to add the type when callng provide.

Is there anyway I can make calls to the provide method type safe without having to write `provide<int>(....`

I've trivialised the example, the aim is to make a call to a method such as  :

```dart
void provide(Token<T> token, T value);
```

If T is not the correct type then the user should get a compile error.

Comment: "My understanding is that with Dart if I don't follow 'provide' with a type then the type is dynamic." No, not in this case.  You're probably thinking of cases like `List list = [1, 2, 3];` which declares `list` to be a `List<dynamic>`.  In your case, the type will be inferred from the arguments to `provide`. When you call `provide(1, 'A')`, Dart will try to infer `A` from `1` (an `int`) and from `'A'` (a `String`).  Since those are different types, it will use the nearest common base type, which in the case of `int` and `String` is `Object`.

Comment: Java does not complain. A method of `static <A> void test(A v1, A v2) {}` will accept a call of `test("A", 4);`. It's exactly the same as in Dart, the type constraint solver figures out that `T` must be `Object` to satisfy both the arguments.